# Error when using stored procedure from prepared statement: Executing SQL directly; no cursor., SQL state 01000 in SQLExecute

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

When I execute the following prepared statement

```php
$query = "EXEC HISTORY_INSERT @Comment = ?, @Var1 = ?, @Var2 = ?";
$pstmt = odbc_prepare($conn, $query);
odbc_execute($pstmt, array('test', 'xxxx', 'xxxx'));
```

I receive the following error:

> Executing SQL directly; no cursor., SQL state 01000 in SQLExecute

However, if I execute the same query from a non-prepared statement, I receive no such error.

```
$query = "EXEC HISTORY_INSERT @Comment = 'test', @Var1 = 'xxxx', @Var2= 'xxxx'"
odbc_exec($conn, $query)
```

Is there any reason a prepared statement would work improperly for a stored procedure?

Comment: try `$query = "EXEC HISTORY_INSERT ?,?,?";`

Comment: The stored procedure has many other optional parameters, so I need to be able to distinguish which parameter is which

Comment: supply all parameters - those that are not required use `NULL` ( or suitable value ) and see how that goes

Comment: Just got back from trying that...it still throws the same error.

Comment: I assume those are all input parameters, not output? How about `CALL HISTORY_INSERT(?, ?, ?)`

Comment: `CALL HISTORY_INSERT('test','xxx',...)` doesn't seem to be a valid way of calling a stored procedure. SQL-Server management studio does not recognize it as a valid query. Interestingly enough, it throws the same error coming from PHP, so I'm thinking this error is not very descriptive

Comment: Have you tried PDO instead? Much more modern interface and maybe it will work for you?